# Routing in angularjs - conditional routing in otherwise syntax

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

i have the following code in my route provider:

```
project.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
  function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider){

  $routeProvider.
  when('/start',{
  templateUrl: 'start.html',
  controller: 'startController'
  }).
  when('/event',{
  templateUrl: 'event.html',
  controller: 'eventController'
  }).
  when('/report',{
  templateUrl: 'report.html',
  controller: 'reportController'
  }).
  otherwise({
  redirectTo: '/'
  });
```

I have a rootscope variable admin with value of either 1 or 0

My current code sends the user to the start page if an unknown value is given to the route provider. I want the route provider to redirect the user to the **event** page if the user is an admin or to the **start** page if the user isnt an admin when an unknown value is given to the route provider.

I was thinking something like this might work, but it didnt.

```
otherwise({
redirectTo: defaultRedirect
});

$rootScope.admin == 1 ? $rootScope.defaultRedirect = "/event" : $rootScope.defaultRedirect = "/start"
```

It throws me an error. 
Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What was that error? could you post that too..

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr? my page crashes too

Comment: try using ui-router it has more flexibility what you want. It has stateChangeStart, Sucess events which works well in doing authorization and authentication in SPA.

Answer (score 0):

No it will not work like that. Instead what you can do is have resolve in otherwise block, where you can check if loggedin user is admin or not (by checking $rootScope variable or calling authentication service). If service resolves user being admin then you can use $location service to change route using `$location.path("/event")` or `$location.path("/start")`. The code look like:

```
$routeProvider.otherwise({
resolve: {
        load: [
            '$rootScope', '$q', 'authentication', '$location', function ($rootScope, $q, authentication, $location) {
                var defer = $q.defer();
                function chooseRoute() {
                    if (authentication.identity === undefined) {
                        $location.path('/logon');
                    } else {
                        $location.path('/somewhere');
                    }

                    defer.reject();
                }

                if (authentication.identityResolved)
                    chooseRoute();
                else {
                    var unbind = $rootScope.$watch(function () { 
                        return authentication.identityResolved; 
                    }, function (resolved) {
                        if (!resolved)
                            return;

                        chooseRoute();
                        unbind();
                    });
                }

                return defer.promise;
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Another way is, you can check event `$routeChangeStart` in config/run block & then accordingly checking if user is admin you can redirect user to specific routes using $location service.